# No sound plays after changing <audio> src after page load on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, src

I've got a quick n dirty trial here,

```
<body>

  TEST

  <audio src="preview1.mp3" id="audio"></audio>

</body>
```

Then in my javascript console on **desktop**, I do the following:

```
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
audio.play();  // the first audio plays just fine!
audio.pause();
audio.src = 'preview2.mp3';
audio.play();  // the second audio plays fine, too!
```

However, when I do the **exact same thing** on any mobile device (specifically iOS and Android devices are the ones that I've tried), absolutely nothing happens. No audio plays at all.

I've done a ton of searching online but it doesn't seem to be the case for anybody else?

Thoughts?

Comment: Even though I was using an acceptable format, I had a Browser not play a video before. Did you make your `mp3` file via audio conversion?

Comment: The MP3 file that we're playing **works if it's the original `src` of the audio element**, so we know it's not a codec / conversion issue. It only doesn't play if it is made the `src` after initial page load.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with your audio player, please note that in Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and autoplay are disabled by the iOS. No data is loaded until the user initiates it. This means that the audio player is inactive until the user initiates playback by clicking on the play button.

For Android devices:

Chrome does not allow applications to play HTML5 audio without an explicit action by the user, similar to how it is handled by iOS, but differently than how the stock Android browser handles it.

Reference: http://www.wix.com/support/html5/technical-difficulties/browser-compatibility/faq/my-video-is-not-playing-on-my